# JQuery Card Flip Issue

Tags: html, jquery, css

Facing the following problems:

- When the button "A" is pressed the animation works as intended (i.e. card flipped from "Red" to "Blue"). Pressing "A" again will return to card to the original state. This is the expected result.
- Problem One: Begin a sequence (e.g. "A") the card changes from "Red" to "Blue". Press the other button (i.e. "B") the card changes to "Yellow". In this scenario the card should be flipped and returned to the original state. This problem can be observed if you begin with "B".
- Problem Two: Press the "B" button twice. The card sequence should be "Red => Yellow => Red" not "Red => Yellow => Blue => Red".

The buttons are to be treated as two separate entities.

```js
$('#flipA').on('click', function myFunctionA() {
  $('#card').removeClass('flippedB');
  $('#card').toggleClass('flippedA');
})

$('#flipB').on('click', function myFunctionB() {
  $('#card').removeClass('flippedA');
  $('#card').toggleClass('flippedB');
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#card .front {
  background: red;
}

#card .back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#card.flippedA .back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#card.flippedB .back{
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#card.flippedA {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#card.flippedB {
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <div id="card">
    <figure class="front">Frontside</figure>
    <figure class="back">Backside</figure>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="options">
  <p><button id="flipA">A</button></p>
  <p><button id="flipB">B</button></p>
</section>
```

Appreciate the help and advice on this one.

Comment: Click A-A works fine - why do you think this "looks horrible"?  Could be that it's removing the blue from `#card.flippedA` as soon as you click 2nd A.  Move the `background:blue` from `#card.flippedA` to `#card .back` (and yellow to `#card.flippedB .back`).  Without knowing how you want it to work, can't really help more.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, we're almost there only two problems. Explained in some more detail what is to be expected, hope this help?

Answer (score 1):

**A little debugging goes a long way.**
If you press A first and then press B, you can see you have incorrectly removed class on B flip *(and vice versa, obviously, if your sequence went `B -> A`)*

```js
$('#flipA').on('click', function myFunctionA() {
  $('#card').toggleClass('flippedA');
  console.log($('#card').attr('class'))
})

$('#flipB').on('click', function myFunctionB() {
  $('#card').toggleClass('flippedB');
  console.log($('#card').attr('class'))
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 800px;
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.flex {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#options {
 width: 200px;
}

#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#card .front {
  background: red;
}

#card .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#card.flippedA {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#card.flippedB {
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex">
  <section class="container">
    <div id="card">
      <figure class="front">Frontside</figure>
      <figure class="back">Backside</figure>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="options" class="flex">
    <p><button id="flipA">A</button></p>
    <p><button id="flipB">B</button></p>
  </section>
</div>
```

[image]

As per the [jQuery docs on `toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) you also need to pass the original `className` in order to remove the original class, alongside adding the new one, issue is, you need to determine which.

To put it simply, you toggle the first class, then the second, however you don't clean up, resulting being in both cards toggled.

These two following options quickly come to mind:

1. Either creating a default non-fliped class
2. Instead of using toggle adding and removing classes explicitly.

For sake of answer simplicity I'll go with the second option.
So your JS should look something like this:

```
$('#flipA').on('click', function myFunctionA() {
  $('#card').removeClass('flippedB');
  $('#card').toggleClass('flippedA');
})

$('#flipB').on('click', function myFunctionB() {
  $('#card').removeClass('flippedA');
  $('#card').toggleClass('flippedB');
})
```

As to why your card turn yellow, initially I thought there's some weird RGB overlay trickery going on, but it turns out to be simply this line

```
 #card.flippedB {
    background: yellow;
 }
```

---

**Footnote**: This is personal coding preference, but I consider it good practice for callback functions on handlers (such as `on`, or even vanillaJS `addEventListener`), that it's not necessary to be declaring function names, you can simply use so called **anonymous function**.

> Only exception to this being, if you intend to use that function explicitly in a callback - a callback within a callback

So that can be either 
  - `function () {`
or even more preferably the ES6 arrow syntax
  -  `() => {`

This also prevents the *pre*-compiler in the engine to unnecessarily hoist the function declaration to the top of the scope.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Included the changes you suggested into my code, please see above. Having said that still experiencing some issues. Require the yellow this is the option for the button "B" hope the explanation above provides more details as to what is needed?